# Trying to use indexOf to find index value of the array when the buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, arrays, createjs, easeljs, animate-cc

I'm using Adobe Animate CC for a canvas project. I have an array that I assigned events listeners to like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < navBtnArray.length; i++ ){
navBtnArray[i].addEventListener("click", navigationControls);
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to capture the index value of the button that was clicked in the array. I tried like so:

```
function navigationControls(e){

console.log(navBtnArray.indexOf(this));
}
```

But that keeps returning -1. Again this is Animate CC so I don't have access to jQuery. Animate uses the CreateJS and EaselJS library. I used to use indexOf in AS3, but it doesn't seem to work the exact same way.

Comment: I was able to get this working by using the currentTarget property. console.log(navBtnArray.indexOf(e.currentTarget) + " this is button array index");

Answer (score 1):

For that, you can use:

```
function navigationControls(e){
    console.log(navBtnArray.indexOf(e.target));
}
```

If that still doesn't work and `indexOf` can't compare such objects, you can try adding an extra property to the button objects, like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < navBtnArray.length; i++ ){
     navBtnArray[i].addEventListener("click", navigationControls);
     navBtnArray[i].index = i;
}
```

and then do:

```
function navigationControls(e){
    console.log(e.target.index);
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using `e.currentTarget` instead of `target`, in case the button has children. You can also turn off mouse children using `btn.mouseChildren=false`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Although, I think it's a case-by-case scenario depending how graphics are done, since sometimes I got weird returns from shape children using `e.currentTarget`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
 var navBtnArray = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
for(var i = 0; i < navBtnArray.length; i++ ){
(function(index){
      navBtnArray[i].onclick = function(){
              console.log(index)  ;
        }    
    })(i);

}
```

```html
<button class="demo">hi</button>
<button class="demo">hi</button>
<button class="demo">hi</button>
<button class="demo">hi</button>
<button class="demo">hi</button>
```

Comment: That looks like a pure javascript approach. I'm using the Animate platform, and there for using a create js /  easelJS framework inside of Animate. I found this article, but doesn't seem to solve my issue: http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Utility%20Methods.html#method_indexOf